# Is a laptop computer going to save its extra cost compared to a desktop computer due to lower electricity consumption, after more than one year?

Tags: laptop, power-management, desktop-computer

There's a lot of talk with people advising laptop users that they gain only mobility and other advantages while they always lose on money.

But I noticed the monitor of an old desktop computer can go up to 200 watts and even newer ones have PSUs that go to 450 watts at an entry level.

A big laptop of 17+ inches is usually only up to 150 watts.

Comment: it is unlikely that you will save money as parts for laptop are always more expensive compared to those for a desktop whether you are replacing damaged parts or upgrading so whaterver you save on electricity will not makeup for it

Comment: The mobility and other advantages of a laptop can of course translate to money if you need mobility in a business setting.  Might be hard to quantify, but it's worth a swag if you're trying to justify a laptop monetarily.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to answer your question correctly. What laptop are you looking at? What desktop are you looking at? How expensive is electricity in your region? How long do you plan to use the laptop?

I'm going to go and make a lot of assumptions and say no. For example my laptop with 17" screen has 90 W power supply. On the other hand, PCs usually use less than 200 W. The fact that there's a 400 W power supply means that it can provide up to 400 W for internal components at peak power consumption. It doesn't mean that the computer is  using 400 W all the time. Also, 200 W for a monitor is really a lot, unless you compare laptop LCDs with CRTs.

Laptops are more expensive and their maintenance is more expansive and I do not believe that during its lifetime a laptop will be able to pay for itself.

Comment: Also, you can get PSUs that lower the power they use when the PC is on standby or asleep. Also, on an energy efficient point of view, if you continually charge a laptop, the time the battery can run the laptop is reduced. So really, the laptop will spend less time plugged in to the mains at the beginning of its life, but towards the end it would barely spend more then 20 minutes away from a wall socket. This would mean then its not efficient, as energy is being wasted by charging a battery that won't hold a charge.

Comment: If a laptop is plugged in, most of the power saving functions (esp. CPU throttling and display dimming) tend to be disabled anyway. I suspect laptops might actually have [i]worse[/i] power consumption in some cases, as they are often not to be designed for high-performance efficiency.

Comment: @mickburkejnr Actually, ALL modern PSU have to drastically reduce power consumption in stand-by/hibernate. I did some research on that for [this](http://superuser.com/q/230039/36601). @Remy In comments, one * around word is *italic* and two are **bold**.

Comment: Very interesting. I always thought the more expensive PSUs (like my Hiper) could only do this. But from reading your post, I can't understand why a PSU can only use a maximum of 2W when on standby and only 4W when its put to sleep? Wouldn't standby use more power?

Comment: @Remy: FYI, Andreja @'ed you above. FYI @Andreja - only the first `@name` you use in a comment is actually notified, so Remy did not recieve anything from your comment above. (obviously, you should get this because this is your answer).